# Bootstrap collapse two-row-wide-column into one row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to have this layout in Bootstrap:

```
 ___  ______________  ___
| 1 ||  2  2  2  2  || 4 |
| 1 ||  2  2  2  2  || 4 |
| 1 ||__2__2__2__2__|| 4 |
| 1 | ______________ | 4 |
| 1 ||  3  3  3  3  || 4 |
| 1 ||  3  3  3  3  || 4 |
|_1_||__3__3__3__3__||_4_|
```

And I want it to collapse down to:

```
 ____________________
|  2  2  2  2  2  2  |
|  2  2  2  2  2  2  |
|__2__2__2__2__2__2__|
 _____  _____  ______
| 1  1||3  3 || 4  4 |
| 1  1||3  3 || 4  4 |
|_1__1||3__3_||_4__4_|
```

...And I'm stumped! Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way of achieving it, using only Bootstrap helper classes:

```css
/* you obviously don't need this, it's just for this example... */
.row {
  font-size: 6rem;
}
[class^="col-"] {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container d-md-none d-lg-none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
        <div>2</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="text-center">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="text-center">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="text-center">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container d-none d-md-block d-lg-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="text-center">1</div>
      <div class="text-center">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="text-center">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="text-center">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="text-center">4</div>
      <div class="text-center">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: this effectively duplicates the content and shows the correct layout for each screen width, based on Bootstrap's `@media` utilities.

If your content is managing user interactions, involves multi-stepped form completion or managing any type of state, you probably want to use more advanced JavaScript patterns designed for this purpose.